# Exclude those orders which has service code 'AAAA'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

An order can have multiple services. As per the functionality, I have to remove those orders from the selection which have a service code `'AAAA'`.
I mean if an order has two services code `'AAAA'` and `'AAAB'`. Then this must not be included in the output because this order has a Service code `'AAAA'`. Please see the screenshot below for more info.

[image: Without any condition Image]

Query:

```
Select BO.OrderID ,OrderDate ,BackgroundServiceID , BST.BST_Name ,BST_Code from 
BackgroundOrder BO 
JOIN BackgroundOrderService BOS ON BO.OrderID = BOS.OrderID 
JOIN ams.lkpBkgSvcType BST ON BST.BST_ID = BOS.BackgroundServiceID
```

[image: Expected Output Image]

Expected Output Query:

```
Select BO.OrderID ,OrderDate ,BackgroundServiceID , BST.BST_Name ,BST_Code from 
BackgroundOrder BO 
JOIN BackgroundOrderService BOS ON BO.OrderID = BOS.OrderID 
JOIN ams.lkpBkgSvcType BST ON BST.BST_ID = BOS.BackgroundServiceID
Where BST.BST_Code = 'AAAB' AND BO.OrderID not in 
(Select BO.OrderID from 
BackgroundOrder BO 
JOIN BackgroundOrderService BOS ON BO.OrderID = BOS.OrderID 
JOIN ams.lkpBkgSvcType BST ON BST.BST_ID = BOS.BackgroundServiceID
Where BST.BST_Code = 'AAAA'
)
```

Please suggest some other ways to get the above output without using a not-in statement.

Comment: Please don't use images for data, code or errors. Use formatted text.

Comment: Don't make people guess about your schema. And now is the time to start using best practices such as defining an alias for ever table and using those aliases to reference every column. That also helps others understand your schema. Bad habits are a tax that everyone pays over time.

Comment: And don't re-use aliases in different scopes - that makes your code much more difficult to read and understand. And if you only want to exclude orders with 'AAAA', then why do you filter the rows for 'AAAB'? What happens when another code is introduced? Lastly what **exactly** is the problem with using NOT IN?

Comment: You might want to contemplate using [`not exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to exclude any `BackgroundOrder` that has a `BST_Code` of `'AAAA'` associated with it. Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your query in a `cte` and count the occurences of 'AAAA' per OrderId then filter where it's zero

```
with t as (
    select BO.OrderID, OrderDate, BackgroundServiceID, BST.BST_Name, BST_Code,
        Sum(case when bst_code='AAAA' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by BO.OrderID) cnt=0
    from BackgroundOrder BO 
    join BackgroundOrderService BOS on BOS.OrderID = BO.OrderID 
    join ams.lkpBkgSvcType BST on BST.BST_ID = BOS.BackgroundServiceID
)
select OrderID, OrderDate, BackgroundServiceID, BST_Name, BST_Code
from t
where cnt=0
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions. But I have a simmilar problem in a live project. There are big amount of data in production environment. It may be slow for big data. Also, Above query was placed in view.  There are 15 types of services there but we only need order with two types of services.

Comment: @DipeshNagpal . . . I don't understand your comment.  This answers the question that asked.